# Is it possible to access all levels in javascript class hierarchy?

Tags: javascript, class, hierarchy

So I'm curious if it's possible from a base (parent) class to access static properties from all levels in a class hierarchy.

Let's paint an example:

```
class Tier1 {
  static NUMBERS = ['one', 'two'];

  getNumbers() {
    // how to do here?
    return this.constructor.NUMBERS.join(', ');
  }
}

class Tier2 extends Tier1 {
  static NUMBERS = ['three'];
}

class Tier3 extends Tier2 {
  static NUMBERS = ['four', 'five'];
}

class Tier4 extends Tier3 {
  static NUMBERS = ['six'];
}

const t1 = new Tier1(); t1.getNumbers(); // Expect to get "one, two"
const t2 = new Tier2(); t2.getNumbers(); // Expect to get "one, two, three"
const t3 = new Tier3(); t3.getNumbers(); // Expect to get "one, two, three, four, five"
const t4 = new Tier4(); t4.getNumbers(); // Expect to get "one, two, three, four, five, six"
```

Is it possible to achieve this effect? Can I traverse down the class instance hierarchy from `this` in a dynamic way?

Would love some input and ideas here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by creating a new static NUMBERS variable at each level that is a copy of the previous one and adding the new items, as follows:

```js
class Tier1 {
  static NUMBERS = ['one', 'two'];

  getNumbers() {
    return this.constructor.NUMBERS.join(', ');
  }
}

class Tier2 extends Tier1 {
  static NUMBERS = [...this.NUMBERS, 'three'];
}

class Tier3 extends Tier2 {
  static NUMBERS = [...this.NUMBERS, 'four', 'five'];
}

class Tier4 extends Tier3 {
  static NUMBERS = [...this.NUMBERS, 'six'];
}

const t1 = new Tier1(); console.log(t1.getNumbers()); // Shows "one, two"
const t2 = new Tier2(); console.log(t2.getNumbers()); // Shows "one, two, three"
const t3 = new Tier3(); console.log(t3.getNumbers()); // Shows "one, two, three, four, five"
const t4 = new Tier4(); console.log(t4.getNumbers()); // Shows "one, two, three, four, five, six"
```

Or if you need to have a **separate** NUMBERS array in each class, and combine them as late as possible (e.g. because their contents could be mutable), then you can follow the approach below. I think this also answers "Can I traverse down the class instance hierarchy from `this` in a dynamic way?" with a definite "yes".

```js
class Tier1 {
  static NUMBERS = ['one', 'two'];

  gatherAllNumbers() {
    const constructors = this.getConstructors();
    return constructors.reverse().map(c => c.NUMBERS).flat();
  }
  
  getConstructors() {
    const result = [];
    let next = Object.getPrototypeOf(this);
    while (next.constructor.name !== "Object")
    {
      result.push(next.constructor);
      next = Object.getPrototypeOf(next);
    }
    return result;
  }
  
  getNumbers() {
    return this.gatherAllNumbers().join(', ');
  }
}

class Tier2 extends Tier1 {
  static NUMBERS = ['three'];
}

class Tier3 extends Tier2 {
  static NUMBERS = ['four', 'five'];
}

class Tier4 extends Tier3 {
  static NUMBERS = ['six'];
}

const t1 = new Tier1(); console.log(t1.getNumbers()); // Shows "one, two"
const t2 = new Tier2(); console.log(t2.getNumbers()); // Shows "one, two, three"
const t3 = new Tier3(); console.log(t3.getNumbers()); // Shows "one, two, three, four, five"
const t4 = new Tier4(); console.log(t4.getNumbers()); // Shows "one, two, three, four, five, six"
```

Comment: Pretty neat solution. Funny it works with 'this.' in the static context :D Cheers!

Comment: I added an alternative solution that "late combines" the number arrays, only just before the numbers are needed.

Comment: Fantastic, I think this is the winner. At least for this question. Thanks a lot @Peter B